# <unloaded module 'SSLContext'> object is not callable on Mercurial hook

Tags: python, post, mercurial, hook

I have a Ubuntu server running apache and a mercurial set up with a hgweb.cgi script.

What i want to do is to set a incoming hook to send some data through a post request to another server I have, so, in my hgweb.config i have:

```
[hooks]
incoming=python:/var/hg/testing_hook.py:my_hook
```

and my testing_hook.py

```py
import requests                                                                                                                                                                           

def my_hook(ui,repo,**kwargs):    
    params = {'dest':'user1','subject':'incoming','message':'new incoming hook'}
    response = requests.post("https://my-url.net/my_api",data=params)
```

the problem is i get the following error:

```
remoto: adding changesets
remoto: adding manifests
remoto: adding file changes
remoto: added 1 changesets with 1 changes to 1 files
error: incoming hook raised an exception: <unloaded module 'SSLContext'> object is not callable
```

What is weird is if i just call the script through the comand shell it works fine.

It doesn't look like a permission issue since the hook is being called...

Any sugestions?